# How To Filter Images Using Alt Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image gallery, which also has a search box. I want to dynamically hide all the images which don't have an alt attribute that matches what the user is searching. I've tried multiple things, but what keeps happening is all the elements end up getting selected.

I have the following in my html to search:

```
<input type="text" id="text">
```

And the images are nested as follows:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li>
        <a href="img/01.jpg">
            <img src="img/thumb/01.jpg" alt="This is what I want to search">
```

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rodriguesandrewb/photo_gallery_v1/blob/master/index.html
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Comment: give some more information about your code and try to provide fiddle..

Comment: So I want it to be find any part of the alt attribute, and update as your typing it. This is what I have so far, still not working right... https://github.com/rodriguesandrewb/photo_gallery_v1/blob/master/js/script.js Line 93-97

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img:not([alt])').hide();
```

This selects `img` tags that do not have `alt` attribute and add css to make them `hidden`

https://jsfiddle.net/4uwLq9b7/2/

```js
$("#hidebutton").click(function() {
    $('img:not([alt])').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="gallery">
    <li>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wet_Cappuccino_with_heart_latte_art.jpg" alt="Cappuccino">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.makingsense.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/280314espresso.jpg" alt="espresso">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://g3yxi3w953w3xjjaj1xcbuay.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Dollarphotoclub_75628098-e1422257536867.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
<button id="hidebutton">
    hide
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
$('img:not([alt="' + $('#text').val() + '"])').hide();
```

Solution 2:

```
$('img').not('[alt="' + $('#text').val() + '"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

An example below in vanilla JS.

Use `document.querySelectorAll('img');` to select your images.
Check for every image if has a value for the `alt` tag.

https://jsbin.com/hiniliheru/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script>
    var app = {
      hide:function(){
        var elms = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
            if(!elms[i].alt){
                elms[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
      }          
    }
  </script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="app.hide()">
<img src="" alt="This is what I want to search">
  <img src="">
  <img src="" alt="This is what I want to search">
  <img src="">
  <img src="" alt="This is what I want to search">
  <img src="" alt="This is what I want to search">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda dirty but I guess you wan't some kind of a simple search engine that searches the text of each alt-attribute of an image tag.

You may try this just as an example.

```js
function search(v) {
  reset();

  var out = document.querySelectorAll('img:not([alt*="' + v + '"])');
  [].forEach.call(out, function(x) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

function reset() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function(x) {
    x.removeAttribute('style');
  });
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="search(this.value)" placeholder="search..." />

<img src="http://mxamber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/side-blue-color-picture-as-your-ideas-and-decoration-green-color-picture-decoration-style-picture-example-of-good-walking-shoes-for-europe-as-your-one-example-and-idea-style-100x100.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum"
/>
<img src="http://mxamber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/simple-example-that-looks-natural-picture-the-example-of-best-family-vacations-in-florida-style-the-example-of-yellow-and-white-color-that-looks-combine-will-be-one-example-place-that-looks-well-100x100.jpg"
alt="lorem ipsum dolor" />
<img src="https://moodle.org/pluginfile.php/17683/user/icon/moodleorgcleaned_moodleorg/f1?rev=1" alt="sit amet" />
<img src="http://mxamber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/white-example-material-black-color-wall-small-shaped-picture-white-color-plane-ideas-of-well-style-as-your-ideas-netjets-prices-the-flooring-style-that-looks-well-example-plane-100x100.jpg" alt="google"
/>
```